# Filtration of the Rows based on the Year and product_id

Tags: python, pandas, time, prediction, feature-engineering

I have a dataset with columns customer_id, ordered_year, product_id.
I need to drop some of the rows based on a filter - If a product is ordered in 2020 and not ordered in 2021 & 2022.I need to drop these rows.
Any suggestion how to proceed ?

Tried with If conditions but did not got the expected result.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. E.g. try `df.head().to_dict()` and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output. Also, show us what you have tried so far, and why your attempt isn't giving you the result that you expect. See: [Research Effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.